# Random numbers on random areas on mobile browser

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, browser

I have very bizarre problem. On mobile version of the website if I open it on desktop browser everything is fine, but when I open it on mobile browser I have some random numbers (781, 2e, 12e and so on) on some random areas.

[image]

AND this is happening on iphone 5S not on iphone 4s or 5!

even if I'm putting just pure html in it, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>blah blah in div</div>
        <p>blah blah in paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**still getting a unwanted 0 at the bottom:**

[image]

Comment: Is it inevitably the same characters for the same content, or does it vary, even though the content is identical?  And is it always numeric?

Comment: No every time it generates new ones! even if content is identical!
No it puts some letters also

Comment: It looks like this is a proxy server issue! here is the same problem in wordpress website:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/strange-numbersletters-appearing-in-random-areas
And this google page 
https://support.google.com/dfa/partner/answer/134520?hl=en
about Browser/proxy server caching is related to this issue to some extend

But I cannot figure out what should be done!

Answer (score 0):

I added this code

```
header("Cache-Control: no-transform");
```

at the very top of the page, even before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

We just noticed this same problem happening with the mobile version of all of our sites (thousands of sites). For us it appears to be happening on all devices, iphone & androids.

We tried the fix header("Cache-Control: no-transform"); and it does fix the issue.

** UPDATE: We have concluded this is some kind of proxy server issue by the mobile providers. When we switch to WIFI on both Android and Iphone the random characters disappear.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that it looks like an issue by the mobile providers!